# Access style background color

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-selectors, background-color

Good Morning in my timezone.

I want set the background Color of the  tag with the same background color of the selected option.

Code snippet :

```
<style>
   .levelKri1 {
     background-color:#CCFFCC;
   }
   .levelKri2 {
     background-color:#CCFFFF;
   }
</style>

 <select name="matrix" id="matrix" style="visibility: visible;" onChange="alert(this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor)">
      <option style="background-color:blue;" selected="selected" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
      <option class="levelKri2" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

If i choose the first one , the Alert function prints the backgroundColor
If i choose the second one, the one in which the background color is defined on the css class the alert does not print anything

How can i get the background color that was set through the css class ?

**Interner Explorer is the browser**.

Thanks in advance 
Best regards

Answer (score 0):

You can try `window.getComputedStyle(element)` on the select tag's onchange event handler. More info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle

Answer (score 0):

It's RGB colors but hope this helps

```js
var element = document.getElementById('matrix');
element.addEventListener("change", function() {
  console.log(window.getComputedStyle(element.options[element.selectedIndex]).backgroundColor);
});
```

```css
 .levelKri1 {
   background-color:#CCFFCC;
 }
 .levelKri2 {
   background-color:#CCFFFF;
 }
```

```html
 <select name="matrix" id="matrix" style="visibility: visible;">
      <option style="background-color:blue;" selected="selected" value="1">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
      <option class="levelKri2" value="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It works on Chrome but IE is the browser clients use and it always retrieve RGB(0,0,0)

Comment: I workaround through the className attribute, i read the className from the option selected and then set it to the select element

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#matrix").change(function() {
  var _color = $(this).children('option:selected').css('backgroundColor');
  $('#matrix').css('background-color', _color);
});
```

```css
.levelKri1 {
 background-color: #CCFFCC;
}
.levelKri2 {
 background-color: #CCFFFF;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="matrix" id="matrix">
  <option selected="selected">Choose an option</option>
  <option class="levelKri1" value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option class="levelKri2" value="2">Option 2</option>
</select>
```